# Should passengers tell the airline they have mild diarrhoea?

Tags: air-travel

Wikivoyage's [guide to diarrhoea](https://en.m.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Travellers%27_diarrhea) suggests, for mild cases, segregating yourself from others, and changing what you eat or drink.

If a passenger has mild diarrhoea, is it worthwhile informing the airline when checking in? For example, do airlines have the ability to serve drinks more suited to people suffering diarrhoea if told in advance, or to segregate the passenger? Assume that it involves travelling in first world countries, such as KIX to Incheon on T'Way.

Comment: Rejected title: "The airline staff are all adults, so really, ..."

Comment: If you inform them of anything remotely like D&V (diarrhoea and vomiting - and diarrhoea on its own can be seen as a precursor) then you may be refused boarding on medical grounds, and that is the only special treatment you would be getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You request the beverages you prefer and at least to some extent the food you prefer. If you're sure they won't have an option that's ok for you, shop after security and before boarding.

There's no need to segregate you as long as you wash your hands thoroughly after each run to the toilet, and keep your hands to yourself as much as possible.

The one thing that might be relevant is that you might need the toilet urgently while the seat belt sign is on. If that happens your face alone will probably be all the communication you need, and if it's not you can say something to the flight attendants then instead of hoping that the checkin staff passed along a message to them.